# Some questions on iOS app sales and number presentation

Tags: iphone, ios, windows-phone-7

Justr wondering, how are your iOS download/purchase stats tracked? Are they stats from the previous day or further back (like froma week ago)? How does one get paid by Apple? Does it involve submitting US tax forms or something similar?

Just wondering how Apple compares to Microsoft with the way they handle developer app licesnes for their respective phones... Also how do they show up on popular download lists?

With WP7 apps don't show up on the popular download lists until 6 days after the app has been released and until then it's only on the 'new' list, you don't get download stats for apps until six days after it's released and you only get stats from six days ago and before. You have to sign up with tax information and other similar things with microsoft (bunch of strange IRS tax forms need to be filled in and sent in).

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Perhaps you could update this post with how it works on windows phone, so people can compare?

Comment: OK done, so far it doesn't look good for MS :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You sign a contract online, and submit banking info. You get paid "within 45 days of month end" though I usually see payments within 30 days.

Payments only go through when you have $100 (or $150 I forget) in credit for that particular country. This means for countries where you don't sell a lot you will have a rolling credit for months on end. Edit: apparently this isn't the case anymore?

Stats are accessed through iTunes Connect. They refresh at around 3am pacific time with yesterday's stats. You can access daily stats for the past ten days, and weekly stats for the past ~30 weeks.

Edit: weekly stats are the same as daily stats, just viewed as a coarser scale. Daily stats allow you to see trends like a single spike in sales from a blog posting, or which weekday you sell the most. Weekly stats are good for overall trends (are your sales trending up or down?)

Also as mentioned in the comments, there a number of websites and apps that do long term tracking and statistical analysis on app sales figures.

Comment: What's the difference between a daily and weekly stat? Are tehy just grouped by week/by day?

Comment: Also, if you want some more detailed stats and pretty graphs as well as aggregated and translated reviews you can use appfigures.com.

Comment: they don't have the limit per country anymore. they combine all revenue from all countries into one payment. and if that payment reachs the threshold you get paid.